# How to approach building a versioning system for a custom CMS?

Tags: database-design, content-management-system

I am very interested in how to approach building a database schema that would allow a CMS/SharePoint type version control for the data.

Unfortunately, I am having a hell of a time finding and informative articles on the matter.

What I would like to learn are good approaches that can scale well as the DB schema grows more complex.

I mean, is it really as simple as just adding a version column to each table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server has build in capabilities for Change Data Capture http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx if you do not worry about portability then it is a good way. There are many workarounds with version numbers and timestamps, Anchor model is one of them, it might be useful for data warehouse applications http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_Modeling

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is with an additional column `version` in each table which is part of your primary key.

You can also build something more complex or use a database which already does the work for you (e.g. Apache CouchDB).

Comment: Well the database I will be using is SQL Server and the ORM would be Entity Framework 6. I'm just trying to see how one could implement it independent of that. Just by having a schema that allow all rows to have let's say 3 versions that can be rolled back by the user.